# Integrate AliPay with Stripe in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, payment, alipay

I want to integrate Alipay in my flutter application using stripe payments. I am able to add cards and they are working fine. But for Alipay, I can't find any proper solution. Can anyone please help me.

```
var source = await StripePayment.createSourceWithParams(SourceParams(
        returnURL: 'https://shop.example.com/crtA6B28E1',
        type: 'alipay',
        amount: int.parse(amount),
        currency: currency))
    .then((value) => print(value.sourceId));
```

I tried this code to create a source but it is giving me error

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(invalidRequest, null, null)
> E/flutter (17877): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)

Comment: Does your stripe account support alipay? Stripe allows credit cards by default, you need to contact them for any other payment type.

Comment: yes, my account support Alipay. The company has provided me and it's showing active in my dashboard

Comment: is there a more detailed error on https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs maybe (like the backend API returns an error that you only see as invalidRequest in the app?)

Comment: Stripe normally replies with a very detailed, non-technical, plain English error message while you are testing. Use whatever means you have to get the body of that failed call, it will contain the answer to your question.

Comment: Can anyone provide me a document to implement Stripe for Ali Pay using flutter?